# How to access local path from linux server java web application?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've created a webapplication which creates folders when filling destination input ( for example => C:\xxx\xxx path).
When i run on my local (http:\localhost:8080), it works perfectly. it finds local windows path and creates folders.
But now i want to open this webapp to group of people, deployed tomcat on internal unix server (http:\ipnumber\portnumber). 
The problem is that when user fills input with local destination, program code can not find the path or can not access local computer folder structure, it looks unix server folder structure.

How can i achieve this? I use angularjs for frontend with call restapi with http.post, the backend side is java.

```
    package com.ama.ist.controller;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.UUID;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import com.ama.ist.model.CustomErrorType;
    import com.ama.ist.model.Patch;
    import com.ama.ist.service.PatchService;
    @RestController
    public class PatchController {

    @Autowired
    private PatchService patchService;


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://ipnumber:portnumber")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mk", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createFolder(@RequestBody Patch patch) {


        System.out.println("patch ddest: => " + patch.getDestination());
        String iscreatedstatus = patchService.create(patch);
        System.out.println("iscreatedstatus" + iscreatedstatus);
        if (!(iscreatedstatus.equals("Success"))) {
            System.out.println("if success" );
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new CustomErrorType("ER",iscreatedstatus), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        System.out.println("if disinda success" );
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new CustomErrorType("OK",iscreatedstatus), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

//  
    @RequestMapping("/resource")
      public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
      }

}
```

This is Service

```
package com.ama.ist.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDepth;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNProperties;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.BasicAuthenticationManager;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.ISVNAuthenticationManager;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCommitClient;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil;

import com.ama.ist.model.Patch;
import com.ama.ist.model.User;

@Service
public class PatchService {

    public String create(Patch patch) {

        String ConstantPath = patch.getDestination();


        File testFile = new File("");
        String currentPath = testFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("current path is: " + currentPath);


        System.out.println("ConstantPath => " + ConstantPath);
//      if (!(isValidPath(ConstantPath))) {
//          return "invalid Path";
//      }

        // System.out.println("Valid mi " + isValidPath(ConstantPath));

        String foldername = patch.getWinNum() + " - " + patch.getWinName();
        System.out.println(ConstantPath + foldername);

        File files = new File(ConstantPath + foldername);
        if (files.exists()) {
            return "The Folder is already created in that path";
        }

        File files1 = new File(ConstantPath + foldername + "\\Patch");
        File files2 = new File(ConstantPath + foldername + "\\Backup");
        File files3 = new File(ConstantPath + foldername + "\\Backup\\UAT");
        File files4 = new File(ConstantPath + foldername + "\\Backup\\PROD");

        if (!files.exists()) {
            if (files.mkdirs()) {
                files1.mkdir();
                files2.mkdir();
                files3.mkdir();
                files4.mkdir();

                createReadme(ConstantPath + foldername, patch);

                if (patch.isChecked()) {

                    System.out.println("patch.getDestination => " + patch.getDestination());
                    System.out.println("patch.getDetail => " + patch.getDetail());
                    System.out.println("patch.getSvnPath => " + patch.getSvnPath());
                    System.out.println("patch.getWinName => " + patch.getWinName());
                    System.out.println("patch.getWinNum => " + patch.getWinNum());

                    System.out.println("patch.getUserName => " + patch.getUser().getUserName());
                    System.out.println("patch.getPassword => " + patch.getUser().getPassword());
                    ImportSvn(patch);

                }

                System.out.println("Multiple directories are created!");
                return "Success";
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create multiple directories!");
                return "Unknwon error";
            }
        } else {
            return "File name is already exists";
        }

    }

    public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
        System.out.println("path => " + path);
        File f = new File(path);

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("true => ");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("false => ");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void createReadme(String path, Patch patch) {

        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Readme.txt").getFile());

            // System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!" + new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
            // File file = new File("resources/Readme.txt");
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String line;
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + "\\Readme.txt", "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(path + "\\Readme.txt");
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                line = line.replace("#Winnumber", Integer.toString(patch.getWinNum()));
                line = line.replace("#NameSurname", " ");
                line = line.replace("#Type", "Package");
                line = line.replace("#detail", patch.getDetail());


                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String date = sdf.format(new Date());
                line = line.replace("#Date", date);

                line = line.replace("#Desc", patch.getWinName());

                writer.println(line);

                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void ImportSvn(Patch patch) {

        String name = patch.getUser().getUserName();
        String password = patch.getUser().getPassword();
        // String filename = patch.getWinName()
        String filename = patch.getWinNum() + " - " + patch.getWinName();
        String url = patch.getSvnPath() + "/" + filename;

        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = new BasicAuthenticationManager(name, password);

        SVNCommitClient commitClient = new SVNCommitClient(authManager, SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true));
        File f = new File(patch.getDestination() + filename);
        try {
            String logMessage = filename;
            commitClient.doImport(f, // File/Directory to be imported
                    SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url), // location within svn
                    logMessage, // svn comment
                    new SVNProperties(), // svn properties
                    true, // use global ignores
                    false, // ignore unknown node types
                    SVNDepth.INFINITY);
            // SVNClientManager cm =
            // SVNClientManager.newInstance(SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true),authManager);
            //
            // SVNUpdateClient uc = cm.getUpdateClient();
            // long[] l = uc.doUpdate(new File[]{dstPath},
            // SVNRevision.HEAD,SVNDepth.INFINITY, true,true);
        } catch (SVNException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is Angularjs side

```
$scope.Create = function() {
    $scope.obj = [];
    console.log("$scope.svnPath" + $scope.patch.svnPath);
    console.log("$scope.userName" + $scope.patch.user.userName);
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : "http://ipnumber:port/patchinit/mk",
        data : $scope.patch
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

        console.log("Success!! ");
        $scope.obj = response.data;
        $scope.errorMessage = response.data.errorMessage;
        $scope.errorCode = response.data.errorCode;

    }, function myError(response) {

        //$scope.obj = response.statusText;
        $scope.errorMessage = response.data.errorMessage;
        $scope.errorCode = response.data.errorCode;

    });

}
```

Comment: check whether the user you employed to deploy your webapp has reading and writing right to the path and  folder you mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share that folder on windows and mount that shared folder in unix. Once mounted, it can be easily accessed using `samba(smb://192.168.1.117/Your_Folder)`.

Samba is standard on nearly all distributions of Linux and is commonly included as a basic system service on other Unix-based operating systems as well.

Comment: Thank you for your clarify response